# netscape.javascript.JSException: null in java applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet, japplet

I have developed a Java applet that uses PCSC readers to detect cards and call a javascript method for each card detected. So the applet is embeded in a web page with the corresponding javascript method.

I use:

> JSObject jsObj = JSObject.getWindow(this);
>
> jsObj.call(method, parameters);

This applet works fine on many browsers and operating sytems (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Windows >= Xp, MacOS, etc.).

But sometimes, the call to the javascript method fails unexpectingly. Here is the exception received:
**netscape.javascript.JSException: null**

What is weird is the null message. As the error happens on other people computers, I just received an report concerning the error, and I have never been able to reproduce it. It happens on any browser.

Has anyone already gotten this error? What could be the cause?

Here is the trace:

> netscape.javascript.JSException: null
>   sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.newJSException(Unknown
>   Source)
>   sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.waitForReply(Unknown
>   Source)   sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.call(Unknown
>   Source)

Thanks

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: The problem is that I cannot reproduce the problem, so that would not be a verifiable example.

Comment: At least show the entire method that includes that code, as well as any method that calls it.  Also include the exact HTML used to launch the applet.